# HQL Left Join - org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter - Path expected for join

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql

While executing the below code, I got this exception

> ERROR org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter -  Path expected
>   for join!

Entity class for DB view:

```
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "find", 
            query = "SELECT v.cxxx, trk.cxxx, trk.ixxx"
        + "FROM AxxxCxxx as v LEFT JOIN AxxxCxxxTxxx as trk "
        + "ON v.cxxx = trk.cxxx "
        )
})

@Entity
@Table(name = "V_XXX")
public class AxxxCxxx implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "CXXX")
private String cxxx;
//getter, setter 
}
```

Entity1 class for DB table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_XXX")
public class AxxxCxxxTxxx extends Super implements
    Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name = "CXXX")
private String cxxx;
//getter, setter
}
```

Super class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Super implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1413197336548058176L;

@Id
@Column(name = "TXXX", nullable = false)
private Integer txxx;

@Column(name = "IXXX", length = 15)
private String ixxx;
//getter, setter

}
```

When I try to execute the NamedQuery, I got this exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: find
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:504)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:802)
... 26 more

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [SELECT v.cxxx, trk.cxxx, trk.ixxx"
    + "FROM AxxxCxxx as v LEFT JOIN AxxxCxxxTxxx as trk "
    + "ON v.cxxx = trk.cxxx]
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.InvalidPathException: Invalid path: 'trk.ixxx'
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.LiteralProcessor.lookupConstant(LiteralProcessor.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
```

Please, can somebody help me? How could I solve the left join with view and table using JPQL for MappedSuperClass?

Comment: How did you solve it???

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use @NamedNativeQuery for SQL queries. With @NamedQuery the query expression is HQL.

Considering the above mapping, you can't really make HQL join, you can use just cartesian product

```
@NamedQuery(name = "find", 
        query = "select v.cxxx, trk.cxxx, trk.ixxx "
    + "from AxxxCxxx as v, AxxxCxxxTxxx as trk "
    + "where v.cxxx = trk.cxxx "
    )
```

})

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the relation between the entities if you want to use JOIN in a JPQL query.

Something like

```
  FROM AxxxCxxx as v INNER JOIN v.axxxCxxxTxxx as trk.
```

where `axxxCxxxTxxx` is a field declared in `AxxxCxxx` class and mapped correctly depending on the DB structure.

Additional info can be obtained [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_03/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_path)